# Recursive function to convert characters

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to write a program in Python which uses a recursive function to convert all the lower-case characters in a string to the next character. Here's my attempt:

```
def convert(s):

    if len(s) < 1:
        return ""

    else:
        return convert(chr(ord(s[0+1])))

print(convert("hello"))
```

When I try to run this program, it gives me the error: string index out of range. Could anyone please help me correct this? I'm not even sure if my program is coded correctly to give the required output :/

Comment: And what is *next* here? The next character in the string, so `h` is replaced by `e`? Or the next character in the alphabet, replacing `h` with `i`? What happens at the edges (so the last character or `z`)?

Comment: I meant the next alphabet character. For instance, "hello" will output "ifmmp". The last character, z, should be transformed to 'a'. Anything you could do to help correct my program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to return the shifted character and then call your `convert` function on the remainder of the string. If you must use recursion, you need to check if the string is exhausted (`if not s` is the same as `if len(s) == 0` here because `''` is equivalent to `False`) and bail:

```
def convert(s):
    if not s:
        return ''
    c = s[0]
    i = ord(c)
    if 96 < i < 123:
        # for lower-case characters permute a->b, b->c, ... y->z, z->a
        c = chr(((i-97)+1)%26 + 97)
    return c + convert(s[1:])

print(convert('hello'))
print(convert('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'))
```

Output:

```
ifmmp
bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyza
```

The ASCII codes for 'a' and 'z' are 97 and 122 respectively, so we only apply the shift to characters whose codes, `i`, are in this range. Don't forget to wrap if the character is `z`: you can do this with modular arithmetic: `((i-97)+1)%26 + 97`.

EDIT explanation: Subtract 97 so that the code becomes `0` to `25`, then add `1` mod 26 such that `0+1 = 1`, `1+1 = 2`, ..., `24+1 = 25`, `25+1=0`. Then add back on `97` so that the code represents a letter between `a` and `z`. This way your letters will cycle round

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I haven't understood the code:  
`((i-97)+1)%26 + 97`. Could you please explain how this works?

Comment: @John: I've edited in an explanation. For more on modular arithmetic, see [the wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) on the subject.

Comment: It might be more readable/understandable with `ord('a') <= i <= ord('z')` and `c = chr(((i-ord('a'))+1)%26 + ord('a'))`

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to index the *second* character each time; Python indexes start at `0` so `0+1` is `1` is the second character. Your `len()` test doesn't guard against that, it only tests for empty strings.

You also pass in just one character to the recursive call, so you always end up with a string of length 1, which doesn't have a second character.

So your test with `'hello'` does this:

```
convert('hello')
    len('hello') > 1  -> True
    s[0+1] == s[1] == 'e'; chr(ord('e')) is 'e'
    return convert('e')
        len('e') > 1 -> True
        s[0+1] == s[1] -> 'e'[1] raises an index error
```

If you wanted to use recursion, then you need to decide how to detect the end of the recursion path correctly. You could test for strings shorter than *2* characters, for example, as there is no *next character* to use in that case.

You also need to decide what to delegate to the recursive call. For a conversion like this, you could pass in the *remainder* of the string.

Last but not least, you need to test if the character you are going to replace is actually lowercase.

Comment: Oh, I see what you are saying. How can I write the code so that each lowercase character is converted to the next character of the alphabet?

Comment: @John: sorry, I was out of time (meeting); I see you already got an answer!